# How can the term "Mud Blood" be a slur when THE recognized G.O.A.T. Wizard, Merlin, was half Muggle?

Tags: harry-potter, muggles, squib

The *Harry Potter-verse* seems to roughly line up with the then-real world of the 1990s. That being the case, unless there was some lore change within the series, Merlin, recognized in both realities as arguably **The** Greatest Wizard of All Time, would *also* be considered a "mud-blood". This is because, by legend, Merlin was born to a purely human [i.e. Muggle] mother. I have come across no place in *Harry Potter* literature that contradicts this.

So my question is: Why, or *how* then, is being a "mud blood" something to be shamed for?

I'm guessing J.K. Rowling simply needed *some* basis for her magical Nazi/Death Eaters to discriminate on to provide greater conflict in the story... but this doesn't even make sense considering that *both* Voldemort **and** his most trusted agent, Severus Snape, were **born to at least one muggle parent!** Ironically, this could be rowling making a subtle commentary on the baselessness of *any* form of racism or prejudice, but its still never clearly explained beyond being the driving issue of the Death Eaters, after loyalty to/fear of Voldemort.

Considering these are some of the strongest wizards of their respective ages... wouldn't being a "half blood" then possibly be a *good* thing?

Wouldn't thing *also* be especially true considering they *can* use magic, as opposed to Squibs (non-magical children of 2 magical parents) who simply can't, *at all?*

Furthermore, is there some kind of "One-drop rule" or an in-story equivalent that defines what a "Mud-Blood" is beyond having a Muggle parent?

I read all of the main series and *some* of the auxiliary tales and support books, but I have come across nothing solid; can anyone supply any text-supported answers to these questions, please? It would make for an awesome discussion.

Comment: racial superiority / slurs know no logic. Voldemort and Snape's bloodlines also serve to demonstrate the idiocy and cognitive dissonance of such beliefs

Comment: I see you've assumed that Merlin is half-Muggle based on his real world origin story. Is there any indication that Merlin's origin ***in the Harry Potter universe*** is the same?

Comment: also is there ever a case of half blood being called a mudblood in the books?

Comment: @NKCampbell Agreed, but it kind of sticks out as a logical fallacy of the books. Hence me asking if there are any examples of how this is quantified or explained in ways that I may have missed.

Comment: yeah - it's a logical fallacy intended to stick out. Characters even point it out. It's not an oversight. It's intentional dramatic irony

Comment: Since merlin went to hogwarts and was in slytherin house, id imagine, like with voldemort, his halfblood status was not well known, if not obscured completely

Comment: Out of universe, although [it isn't true](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adolf_Hitler#Ancestry), it is widely believed that Hitler had Jewish ancestry.  This may have been one of the influences behind giving Voldemort a Muggle father.

Comment: that's *exactly* what she was doing w/ Voldemort.

Comment: *I made a an unfounded assumption and it doesn't fit* Then I guess stop making those assumptions? Merlin in the HP verse isn't the same as the mythological Merlin.

Comment: @Valorum **Note:** I _specifically_ stated that it "seems to line up with the real world of the 1990s," and "unless there was some lore change"; I _never pressummed_ the two were exact. Hence me asking **If anyone knows if this may not be the case.** All we have to go on is that HP Merlin:
1. Existed centuries before, attending Hogwarts
2. Was an immensely powerful Master Wizard of King Arthur's Court
3. Was one of the greatest Wizards of his time
4. He held wizardkind should help Muggles thus founded the Order of Merlin to promote Muggle rights, creating rules against using magic on them.

Comment: @Valorum A lot of the "assumptions" of Merlin being human born came from _Harry Potter: Hogwarts Mystery._

Comment: @Himarm Draco called Hermione a "mud blood" in book 2 or 3. One of her parents is human.

Comment: @RussRainford Hermione is called a mudblood because shes muggle born... both of her parents are muggles. there is not a single half blood called a muggle born or mudblood in the series. the point of the slur, is that her blood is mud due to double muggle parents. Harry and Voldemort both have very famous and well respected pureblood in their veins, mixed with a slight taint of muggle blood.

Comment: @HarryJohnston Again, not disagreeing; this is why I pointed out "Ironically, this could be rowling making a subtle commentary on the baselessness of any form of racism or prejudice, but its still never clearly explained beyond being the driving issue of the Death Eaters, after loyalty to/ fear of Voldemort." Again, this is an inference, though, not something that was outrighted stated, and I'm just wondering if this is clear to others, or if perhaps I was reading too much into it.

Comment: the canonicity of HPHM game is...murkey - and again, her commentary isn't "so subtle" at all - it's practically bonk bonk on the head in book 2

Comment: @Himarm To my knowledge, "Half-blood" is the term commonly given to wizards and witches who had known Muggle or Muggle-born parents _or_ grandparents. You are correct about Hermione, though; doesn't alter the fact that very few families in HP are still "pureblood", and that _most_ of the wizards and witches in HP cannon are Half-blood, including characters like Seamus. "Mudblood" _can_ be used, however, as a slur for a Muggle-born **or** half-blood wizard or witch. This is because "Pure bloods" thought that even the _possibility_ of a half blood could result in a child with a loss of magic.

Comment: @NKCampbell LOL... I suppose I could see that, but again, it may just have been a basis for conflict, as opposed to commentary. Then again, just as highly skilled magic users can come from pure muggles and squibs can come from  Pure Bloods, this may just be a case of a recessive gene manifesting itself in both cases, and the "fear" of lost magic being used to show the power of propaganda and fear mongering within the series. rowling is a careful writer, so I have no doubt she planned some of it, but it just makes less sense [in story] when taking Merlin and his legend into context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Never underestimate the human capacity to hold mutually incompatible or hypocritical beliefs, especially when it comes to constructs like race, class, or the equivalent, which the whole "mudblood" thing is an obvious reference to.

Real life example, right now; there are people in the United States strongly opposed to immigration from the "wrong" countries, and who, openly or not, would vastly prefer only white people to be the ones coming in. Some of these people are of Jewish, Irish, and/or Italian ancestry. The problem is, not that very long ago, Jewish, Italian, and Irish immigrants were very much not considered "white", and many early laws regarding immigration into the United States were originally meant to reduce the number of them getting off the boat.

So you don't need some sort of explanation as to why bigoted wizards would hold these sorts of beliefs when you can observe *exactly* that type of thing in the real world.

Answer (score 5):

## Blood purity ensures the line stays magic.

The idea of blood purity is most likely based in the fact that magic is an inherited genetic trait. Though there are examples of both skilled and unskilled wizards of every blood status, and though it’s possible for wizards to be born into families that seem to be entirely Muggle, studies have shown that magic is a genetic trait. Even wizards born to Muggles were found to have inherited it from a wizard ancestor, albeit possibly a very distant one in some cases.

> “As intensive studies in the Department of Mysteries demonstrated as far back as 1672, wizards and witches are born, not created. While the “rogue” ability to perform magic sometimes appears in those of apparent non-magical descent (though several later studies have suggested that there will have been a witch or wizard somewhere on the family tree), Muggles cannot perform magic.” 
> <sub><sup>*- The Tales of Beedle the Bard*</sup></sub>

It’s clear from the evidence given that keeping the bloodline pure does ensure the bloodline stays magical, and that continued intermarriage with Muggles will make descendants become Squibs and later Muggles. The Black family has kept their bloodline pure, and they’ve been consistently mostly wizards since medieval times. The Black family tree is quite full, though any Squibs and blood traitors are blasted off the family tree, meaning from medieval times to the present day, the vast majority of the pure-blood Black family are wizards.

> “The tapestry looked immensely old; it was faded and looked as though Doxys had gnawed it in places. Nevertheless, the golden thread with which it was embroidered still glinted brightly enough to show them a sprawling family tree dating back (as far as Harry could tell) to the Middle Ages. Large words at the very top of the tapestry read
>
> *The Noble and Most Ancient House of Black*
>
> *‘Toujours pur”*
>
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Order of the Phoenix, Chapter 6 (The Noble and Most Ancient House of Black)*</sup></sub>

The genetic trait of having magic is shown to be inheritable. Children born into a wizarding family are highly likely to be wizards themselves, as Squibs are noted to be quite unusual.

> “A Squib is someone who was born into a wizarding family but hasn’t got any magic powers. Kind of the opposite of Muggle-born wizards, but Squibs are quite unusual.” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Chamber of Secrets, Chapter 9 (The Writing on the Wall)*</sup></sub>

It’s also proven that conversely, consistently marrying Muggles will produce less magical descendants. The Scourers, a group of wizard mercenaries, disappeared into Muggle society by marrying Muggles and weeding out any wizard children they produced by these marriages, which wouldn’t be possible if they had produced magical children as consistently as wizard families - they’d have very few children who had no magical abilities and could be kept.

> Several of the most notorious Scourers eluded justice. With international warrants out for their arrest, they vanished permanently into the No-Maj community. Some of them married No-Majs and founded families where magical children appear to have been winnowed out in favour of non-magical offspring, to maintain the Scourer’s cover. 
> <sub><sup>*[- Seventeenth Century and Beyond (Pottermore)](https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/seventeenth-century-and-beyond-en)*</sup></sub>

Therefore, it’s very clear that having a large number of wizards in the bloodline does greatly increase the likelihood that the bloodline will remain a wizarding one in future generations. Because of this, examples of powerful wizards who weren’t pure-blood wouldn’t change a family’s desire to keep their bloodline pure. Knowing that it’s possible for other blood statuses to be powerful  wouldn't negate the fact that marrying only wizards would still make it far more likely that the majority of those born to their bloodline would be wizards.

## Merlin’s blood status is never stated.

Though Merlin is described as having a non-magical parent in other works, there’s nothing within the information given about him in Harry Potter that indicates whether this is true or not. Therefore, it can’t be said whether Merlin is an example of a powerful wizard who isn’t pure-blood, since his blood status remains unknown.

## Mudbloods have two Muggle parents.

The definition of what makes a Mudblood is indeed given. Mudbloods are born to two Muggle parents.

> “It’s about the most insulting thing he could think of,’ gasped Ron, coming back up. ‘Mudblood’s a really foul name for someone who was Muggle-born – you know, non-magic parents.” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Chamber of Secrets, Chapter 7 (Mudbloods and Murmurs)*</sup></sub>

Wizards who have one magical parent and one Muggle parent, as well as wizards who have two magical parents but have Muggle ancestry in their bloodline, are half-bloods.

Comment: Is there any evidence that a Muggle-born wizard is less likely to pass on the genetic trait of magic than a pure-blood wizard?

Answer (score 0):

There is a considerable flaw in the original question, so this is more like a comment than an answer.  The flaw is in saying that Merlin seems to be the same in Harry Potter as in medieval stories that modern readers variously classify as history, pseudo history, historical fiction, legends, or myths.

Thee was an episode of the Disney Channel sitcom *Shake it Up* (2010-2013), "Shake it Up, UP, and Away" (2 October 2011) where the protagonists CeCe and Rocky are hired to dance on the wing of an old World War One biplane - while it is flying.  Told that the incredibly old man who will fly the plane was its pilot during World War One (1914-1918), CeCe asks if she should worry and Rocky grimly replies CeCe should be glad she isn't good at math - or history.

https://www.imdb.com/title/tt2049257/?ref_=ttep_ep3[1](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt2049257/?ref_=ttep_ep3)

I guess J.K. Rowling has no reason to feel really bad about not being good at math - or apparently history - but maybe sometimes she might regret not being a little bit better at them.

> Established around the 10th century, Hogwarts is considered to be one of the finest magical institutions in the Wizarding World, though other notable schools included Beauxbatons Academy of Magic in France, the Durmstrang Institute in Scandinavia, and Ilvermorny School of Witchcraft and Wizardry in the United States. Children with magical abilities are enrolled at birth, and acceptance is confirmed by owl post at age eleven. However, if the child in question is a Muggle-born, a staff member from the school visits with the child and his or her family in order to inform them of their magical heritage and the existence of the Wizarding world.
>
> Hogwarts was founded around 990 A.D. by four of the greatest wizards and witches of the age: Godric Gryffindor, Helga Hufflepuff, Rowena Ravenclaw, and Salazar Slytherin. They each represented an aspect of personality that they wanted to bring out in new students. However, shortly after founding the school, Slytherin had a falling out with the other founders about blood purity, and wanted to admit only pure-blood students. He felt pure-blooded students deserved to learn magic, and those of other ancestry such as Muggle-borns and Half-bloods, were unworthy. The other three founders all disagreed, especially Gryffindor. Slytherin left the school, but not before secretly building the Chamber of Secrets. He foretold that only his own heir would be able to open it once he or she arrived at the school, and the heir would unleash a murderous basilisk living inside to purge the school of all Muggle-born students.

Merlin is listed as a notable member of Slytherin House

https://harrypotter.fandom.com/wiki/Hogwarts_School_of_Witchcraft_and_Wizardry[2](https://harrypotter.fandom.com/wiki/Hogwarts_School_of_Witchcraft_and_Wizardry)

> At some point in the tenth century, four of the greatest witches and wizards that ever lived founded Hogwarts School of Witchcraft and Wizardry. Their names were Godric Gryffindor, Rowena Ravenclaw, Helga Hufflepuff and Salazar Slytherin.

https://www.pottermore.com/features/origins-of-hogwarts-school-of-witchcraft-and-wizardry[3](https://www.pottermore.com/features/origins-of-hogwarts-school-of-witchcraft-and-wizardry)

> Merlin
>   Merlin himself was sorted into Slytherin when he was at Hogwarts, and the young wizard went on to become one of the most famous wizards in history. The Order of Merlin, named to commemorate him, has been awarded since the fifteenth century. Legend has it that the First Order of Merlin’s green ribbon reflects his Hogwarts house.

https://www.pottermore.com/features/famous-slytherins-through-the-ages[4](https://www.pottermore.com/features/famous-slytherins-through-the-ages)

If what those two sources say about Merlin is based on canon, Merlin would have attended Hogwarts sometime between when it was founded in the 10th century (901-1000) and when the order of Merlin was first awarded in the 15th century (1401-1500).

So the period of European History when Merlin might have attended Hogwarts would have been sometime during the Early Middle Ages (roughly 500-1000), or the High Middle Ages (roughly 1000--1250), or the Late Middle Ages (roughly 1250-1500).

So therefore one would suppose that either Merlin was only about eleven years old sometime during the 10th to 15th centuries, or else for some reason an adult Merlin used advanced magic to disguise himself as a little boy to attend Hogwarts and be taught elementary magic, or else Hogwarts also taught post graduate advanced magic courses for adult wizards in those days.

Anyway, if those statements about when Hogwarts was founded and that Merlin studied there in Slytherin House are based on canonical sources, they give absolutely no evidence indicating that the Merlin in *Harry Potter* would have been born before AD 900, and absolutely no proof that he was born before 1400.

And therefore anyone familiar with what was written about King Arthur and Merlin during the Early, High and Late Middle Ages in works that modern readers variously classify as history, pseudo history, historical fiction, legends, or myths, doesn't need to read any further, for I will have already proved my point.

The famous wizard Merlin known to witches and wizards in *Harry Potter* was a different person from the famous "wizard" Merlin known to us.  The Merlin we know was already the subject of oral and written tales that might be classified as history, pseudo history, historical fiction, legends, or myths, when the *Harry Potter* Merlin would have lived during the Late, High, or even Early Middle Ages.  The *Harry Potter* Merlin could have heard or read stories about the earlier Merlin when he was a child.

Thus it would be chronologically possible for the *Harry Potter* Merlin to have been named after our Merlin, the possibly more or less real Merlin, and possibly some of his fame in Harry Potter's lifetime could be due to mixing up the two (or possibly more?) Merlins.

See my answer to this question: [Once Upon a Time - Merlin Timeline inconsistency?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/107551/once-upon-a-time-merlin-timeline-inconsistency/181848#181848)[5](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/107551/once-upon-a-time-merlin-timeline-inconsistency/181848#181848)